# Why is p element taking up more space than needed?

Tags: html, css

```css
.logo{
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #1f0e3e;
}

p {
  border: solid red;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -53px;
  left: -75px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(100px) rotate(48deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;

  transform: translate(100px) rotate(48deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class= "logo nav-txt" style="cursor:pointer;">K<p>text</p></div>
```

you can see my html + css above in the code snippet. You can also see that the border around the p element is taking much more space then required to cover the text. How do I make the p element only take up the space that is required to cover the text? I want the border to be surrounding the text with no space between the border and the text.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/md2yzboz/1/) is a fiddle demo of the html/css

Comment: try to manipulate font-size and the width of container. I didn't really got your question. Maybe you should consider adding more exact description of the final state you want?

Comment: I edited the question. I hope that makes it more clear. I want the border to be surrounding the text with no space between the border and the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust it's `line-height` property:

[**MDN's docs:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

> **line-height:**
>   On block level elements, the line-height property specifies the minimum height of line boxes within the element.
>   On non-replaced inline elements, line-height specifies the height that is used to calculate line box height.

```css
.logo{
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #1f0e3e;
}

p {
  border: solid red;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -53px;
  left: -75px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(100px) rotate(48deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;

  transform: translate(100px) rotate(48deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class= "logo nav-txt" style="cursor:pointer;">K<p>text</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this two into P element

```
  line-height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
```

```css
.logo{
  background-color: white;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #1f0e3e;
}

p {
  line-height: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid red;
  font-size: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: -53px;
  left: -75px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(100px) rotate(48deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;

  transform: translate(100px) rotate(48deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class= "logo nav-txt" style="cursor:pointer;">K<p>text</p></div>
```